# Clock Does not update trying to use def with Tkinter

Tags: python, function, loops, tkinter, clock

I have made another question that asks how to make a loop with out threads:
[Threads And Time + Tkinter In Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498774/threads-and-time-tkinter-in-python)
But it does not work like a loop. It loads the clock fine but it does not update.

```
import tkinter as tk

import datetime


class FirstFrame(tk.Frame):
    trys = 3
    timecall = datetime.datetime.now()

    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        master.title("Enter password")
        master.geometry("300x300")

        self.clock = tk.Label(self, fg='blue')
        self.update()
        self.clock.pack()        

        self.status2 = tk.Label(self, fg='blue')
        self.status2.pack()
        self.status = tk.Label(self, fg='red')
        self.status.pack()

        self.number = tk.Label(self, fg='red')
        self.number.pack()

        self.trysremain = tk.Label(self, fg='red')
        self.trysremain.pack()

        self.userlbl = tk.Label(self, text='Enter Username')
        self.userlbl.pack()

        self.userE = tk.Entry(self)
        self.userE.pack()
        self.userE.focus()

        self.lbl = tk.Label(self, text='Enter Password')
        self.lbl.pack()

        self.pwd = tk.Entry(self, show="*") 
        self.pwd.pack()
        self.pwd.bind('<Return>', self.check)

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Done", command=self.check)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Cancel", command=self.quit)
        self.btn.pack()

    def update(self, event=None):
            timecall = datetime.datetime.now()
            self.clock.config(text=self.timecall)
            self.after(1000, self.update)


    def check(self, event=None):

        if self.pwd.get() == app.password:
            if self.userE.get() == app.user:
                 self.destroy()
                 self.app= SecondFrame(self.master)
            else:
                self.status2.config(text="Wrong Username")

        else:
            self.trys = self.trys - 1
            self.status.config(text="Wrong password")
            self.number.config(text=self.trys)
            self.trysremain.config(text="Trys remaining")
            if self.trys == 0:
                root.destroy()
                root.quit()


class SecondFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        master.title("Main Application")
        master.geometry("600x400")
        self.c = tk.Button(self, text="Options", command=self.third_frame_open)
        self.c.pack()

    def third_frame_open(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = ThirdFrame(self.master)


class ThirdFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        self.password_set = tk.Label(self, fg='green')
        self.password_set.pack()
        master.title("Options")
        master.geometry("400x300")
        self.but2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go Back", command=self.second_frame_open)
        self.but2.pack()
        self.but1 = tk.Button(self, text="Change password", command=self.showpasswordinput)
        self.but1.pack()
        self.but1.bind('<Return>', self.showpasswordinput)

    def showpasswordinput(self):
        self.but1.pack_forget()
        self.e = tk.Entry(self.master, show="*")
        self.e.pack()
        self.e.focus()
        self.but2 = tk.Button(self, text="Change password", command=self.set_password)
        self.but2.pack()
        self.but2.bind('<Return>', self.set_password)

    def set_password(self):
        self.password_set.config(text="Password Updated")
        setpass = open("password_store.txt", "w")
        passvar = self.e.get()
        self.e.pack_forget()
        setpass.write(passvar)
        setpass.close()

    def second_frame_open(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app= SecondFrame(self.master)

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app=FirstFrame(root)
    user = open("user_store.txt", "r")
    app.user = user.read()
    user.close()
    password2 = open("password_store.txt", "r")
    app.password = password2.read()
    password2.close()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `self.clock.config(text=self.timecall)` should be `self.clock.config(text=timecall)`.

Comment: please don't link to code on another site.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I have changed it now. Wow I go 4 Down Votes... Great.

Comment: @Jake: you got downvotes because a) you linked to code posted on another site, b) you didn't mention the error that you are likely getting, and c) you showed no signs of doing any research or attempts to try and solve this yourself before asking. The standard for questions is a bit higher on stackoverflow than for other places on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I Got some help and I managed to find that at the bit that says:

```
def update(self, event=None):
    timecall = datetime.datetime.now()
    self.clock.config(text=self.timecall)
    self.after(1000, self.update)
```

All I had to do was change the `self.clock.config(text=self.timecall)` To `self.clock.config(text=timecall)`

Credit To https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/rawing